# Running Mavericks. Need to return to Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I am running Mavericks 10.9 on my imac. 
It does not have the same ability of 
slideshows with music in Garageband 
as I had in Snow Leopard 10.6.
Is there any way I can return to Snow Leopard?

Comment: If your iMac came with 10.7 or later, you will probably _not_ be able to use Snow Leopard on it.

Comment: First thank you. I checked this out and it seems to be a big process for a beginner and leading to a lot of troubleshooting. Any way I can just get back garageband from snow leopard without going through this entire process.

Comment: That depends on the version of GarageBand that was on Snow Leopard. Starting with version 6 it was only available on the Mac App Store, I think, and I do not think you'd be able to download it now unless you had purchased it previously. You might want to post a different question. (Also: do you have a Snow Leopard installation with GarageBand installed on it?)

Answer (score 1):

First I backed everything up on time machine, and I made a manual backup of photos, music, downloads, and documents to another HDD.

Next I put in the install disk from OSX Leopard 10.5.. Mavericks will let you enter the install process right from the desktop on Leopard 10.5, but nothing past 10.5. (If you don't have leopard you can probably get one off ebay, or find it on the internet somewhere.

The computer will restart into installation mode from which I erased the HDD. Then I installed 10.5 Leopard.

After the Leopard install you can upgrade to any version you want to. I used snow leopard because it only uses 1 gig of RAM.

My computer runs much faster again, like when I bought it. Sure there are some apps that don't work, but I have everything I need here.